# Mysql Match against where string contains

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, match-against

I have a sql which shall return all results with "lars" in the title.
The result can be "lars dd" but also "larsdd".

The search string shall be contained in the word or be the word.

This is the query I am running:

```
SELECT wp_14_faq_search.title,
MATCH (title) AGAINST ('lars*') AS title_relevance                  
FROM wp_14_faq_search 
WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('lars*')
```

This query returns results like: "lars dd" or "lars 123". But not "larsddd".

How do I have to modify my query, that it also returns "larsdd".

I need match, because I order the results by relavancy.

Comment: why you aren't using **like**...

Answer (score 0):

try like operator..

```
select title from wp_14_faq_search 
where title like 'lars%'
```